# Super capacitor in UPS system instand of battery

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, ups, supercapacitor

I got an idea to use super capacitors in UPS system like battery replacemant. I have UPS what give me 220V/2000W what use 3 batteries 12V/7,2A.

That UPS power whole my office (lights, computers, monitors) for 2 hours with no electricity. I want to get more efficient power source for my UPS and think that super capacitors can be good solution.

What you think and what capacitors to use?

Comment: Search this site for supercapacitors.  Similar questions have been asked before.  Supercapacitors of size comparable to a battery cannot provide any where close to as much energy as the battery.  And, supercapacitors cost much more.

Comment: 7.2Ah is a pretty small battery.  A Car battery ~ 50Ah =  600Wh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good idea. Capacitors & Supercapacitors are designed to be used for short pulses of high current. A UPS is not a great application for them, which is why they use batteries. In any case, let's do the math.

Let's assume you want to use [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/AVX/SCCZ1EB308VCB?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsCu9HefNWqpmIe8hz%2fozG9p6tpFf3jMBMNp1yx6GPEPw%3d%3d) supercapacitor. The specs are:

> Capacitance: 3000F
>
> Max Voltage: 2.7V
>
> Cost: $56
>
> Dimensions: 6cm*13cm

You say your current 2000W ups powers your office for 2 hours. This means that it can store
$$2000W * 2 h * 60 m * 60 s = 14.4MJ$$
Each capacitor can store
$$ 0.5*C*V^2 = 0.5*3000*2.7^2 = 10.9kJ$$
So you need:
\$ \frac{14.4* 10^6}{10.9*10^3}=1317 \$ capacitors, which would cost you $73,745, and take up half a cubic meter of space. Not to mention Transistor's point that a UPS expects its batteries to be putting out a roughly constant voltage, which these capacitors won't do. You'd either need to redesign the UPS or throw even more capacitors at the problem. Either way, it's not a practical solution for UPS energy storage, which is why no one uses supercaps for their UPS.

Comment: eligible for wholesale discount though ;)

Comment: Brings it down to $51,000. Still a far cry from $250 of lead-acid batteries

Answer (score 1):

You have shown no calculations.

Assuming you mean 7.2 Ah (not A) then your stored energy is 3 x 12 V x 7.2 A = 260 Wh. There is no way that you can get 2000 W x 2 h = 4000 Wh from those batteries.

Note that batteries give out a fairly constant voltage through their discharge. Your super-capacitors' voltage will fall as they discharge.